# New trainers - leaky sole!

Tags: shoes, repair

I recently got some new trainers (Adidas Neo) and oddly, the left shoe seems to have sprung a leak.

There are no apparent holes in the sole (heck, I can't see any wear on them at all!) and its not coming in through the mesh toe covering, as its only the ball and heel of my foot that gets wet.

The right shoe gets a little damp, but nowhere near as much as th left one.

Is there anything I can do? I love these trainers and would love to be able to walk in mildly wet weather without worrying about wet feet!

Comment: If they are new, take them back to the shop for a refund.

Comment: They are about 2 weeks old and sadly the shop receipt states returns ust be unused. It's just in the past week that we've had terrible weather and I've noticed it.

Comment: But it's not a "return because you don't want them any more", but a "return as defective".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is to take them back for a refund. They're unfit for the purpose for which they were sold.

Failing that, contact the manufacture and get them to repair / replace the shoes.

Anything else you do to fix the problem is likely to make it impossible to return them.

Comment: I took them back, didn't even have to break out the speech about statutory rights and got a full refund :)

Answer (score 1):

In the short term, you can use sealskinz waterproof socks. It might be worth it to try to determine if it is indeed the sole or perhaps the upper. I would start with a plastic bag to block water passing through the insole. If your sock gets wet, your problem is the upper; if it stays dry while the insole gets get wet - you guessed it - it's the sole.